# Resume for audiobooks?

Tags: lumia, audio

Does windows phone have resume for audiobooks? I'm currently using an iphone and looking to switch to a Lumia. One of the key uses I have for the phone is listening to audiobooks in m4b format. The iPhone classifies all m4b files as audiobooks and support resume from the place from which a file was paused for such files (This is through the regular music application on the iPhone. I am not using any purchased app for the iPhone for this.)

Comment: I don't have experience with audiobooks, but your experience might be better with services such as audible.com that have windows phone apps instead of iTunes m4b with DRM (which might even restrict you to Apple devices).

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert on my lumia 610 using windows 7.8 but i do listen to a lot of audiobooks and I can tell you is as long as I listen to only one file I can stop it and resume it as often as I like without losing my place, but do remember that to listen to audiobooks on a windows phone you have to convert m4b files to mp3 as the m4b is an itunes format and is not recognized by a windows phone. It’s easy to do as there are a number of converter apps or you can convert on itunes itself. I hope this is of help.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I found one dedicated audiobook player which I could successfully test without paying.  It was also ad-free, yay!

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/audiobooked/9wzdncrdrjwq

Each audiobook you want to play, you will have to add the folder (or individual files) to the app.

I tested it with adding an individual file to the app.  It seems to have renamed it to add an `.m3b` file extension on the end, to indicate an **mp**3 audio **b**ook.  I don't see this as a great idea, but it doesn't look like a deal-breaker.

At first I thought the lockscreen play/pause button was broken; this was due to a bug.  If you use the lockscreen skip button, when you are already on the last chapter, it keeps playing but the lockscreen button back changes as if it had stopped, and no longer works.